# Converting Chebyshev expansion into a regular polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials

So I have a very very basic technique for converting shifted Chebyshev polynomials to regular polynomials but it seems to have a large issue with numerical stability and I don't completely understand why (but I partially do). The problem even seems to occur in a less exaggerated way for unshifted Chebyshev polynomials of higher degree.

First I'll start out be defining what I mean by the shifted Chebyshev polynomials. Let $L^{[a,b]} : [-1, 1] \to [a, b]$ be the affine map from [-1, 1] such that $L^{[a, b]}(-1) = a$ and $L^{[a, b]}(1) = b$. We define the shifted Chebyshev polynomials $T^{[a, b]}_n(x) : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by the following recurrence relation.

$$T^{[a, b]}_0(x) = 1$$
$$T^{[a, b]}_1(x) = L^{[a,b]}(x)$$
$$T^{[a, b]}_n(x) = 2 \cdot L^{[a,b]}(x) \cdot T^{[a, b]}_{n-1}(x) - T^{[a, b]}_{n-2}(x)$$

The regular Chebyshev polynomials $T_n(x) = T^{[-1, 1]}_n$ are a special case. One can also prove that $T_n(L^{[a,b]}(x)) = T^{[a, b]}_n(x)$

Now lets say I have an approximation of $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ by the truncated Chebyshev expansion $P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k T^{[a, b]}_k(x)$. I can evaluate $P(x)$ using Clenshaw's algorithm with good success and we can see that $P(x) \approx f(x)$ for $x \in [a, b]$

How ever if I convert $P(x)$ to be represented as a standard polynomial $\sum_{k=0} a_k x^k$ and I then evaluate this polynomial with Horner's method I hit big issues. The results are off by a good bit and often more naive methods than using Chebyshev approximation produce better results than this converted polynomial. I use the following technique to do the conversion.

Let $L^{[a, b]}(x) = Ax + B$ then let $C^{[a, b]}_n(k)$ be the $k$th coefficient of $T^{[a, b]}_n(x)$, the following (rather complicated) recurrence defines it (you can ignore all but the last equation here to understand the remainder of my question)

$$C^{[a, b]}_0(0) = 1$$
$$C^{[a, b]}_1(0) = B$$
$$C^{[a, b]}_1(1) = A$$
$$C^{[a, b]}_n(0) = 2 B \cdot C^{[a, b]}_{n-1}(0) - C^{[a, b]}_{n-2}(0)$$
$$C^{[a, b]}_n(k) = 2 A \cdot 2 C^{[a, b]}_{n-1}(k-1) + B \cdot C^{[a, b]}_{n-1}(k) - C^{[a, b]}_{n-2}(k) \,\,\, 0 < k < n$$
$$C^{[a, b]}_n(n) = 2 A \cdot 2 C^{[a, b]}_{n-1}(n-1)$$

After we have this $a_k = \sum_{j=0}^n c_j \cdot C^{[a, b]}_j(k)$ and it kinda seems like this works in practice but the values of $C^{[a, b]}_n(n) = 2^{n-1}A^n$ are very large which seems to be causing the issue of numerical instability. It doesn't really seem like the computation of $C^{[a, b]}_n(n)$ itself is numerically stable frankly.

Is there a way to adapt this to improve stability? Is there a better technique for converting from Chebyshev approximations to regular polynomials? Is it just the case that these coefficients get very large and thus nothing can be done about this issue?

Comment: Probably can't do anything about this. Numerical Recipes mentions this issue; if you're going to work with higher degree polynomials (say for $n \ge 5$) then stay within Chebyshev-land.

Comment: If you can provide a reference to the source I'd accept that as an answer!